# Laravel is it possible to merge 3 select queries

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have 3 queries that looks like this:

```
$categories = Category::where('cat_id', $mainCatId)->get(['cat_id', 'category_name']);

$subCategories = Subcategory::where('sub_id', $catId)->get(['subcat_id', 'subcategory_name']);

$subSubCategories = SubSubcategory::where('subsub_id', $subCatId)->get(['subsubcat_id', 'subsubcategory_name']);
```

Now I wonder if its possible to merge those queries into one big query?

The queries above can in some cases return null if no result are found

Thanks

Comment: You are querying three different tables. What should the big query return?

Comment: Give the structure of your table, some sample and expected data. A vivid explanation about how to get the expected result will be good too.

Comment: And what do you get if you "merge" those into one big query? There has to be a reason. If the reason is *"I think it's nicer"* or *"It's faster"* - no, those are wrong reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a JSON or Laravel Collection as result, then I would suggest you to go for with() methods.

Add these to your models:-

On Categoriy.php

```
protected $with = ['subcategories'];
public function subcategories(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
}
```

On Subcategory.php

```
protected $with = ['subsubcategories'];
public function subsubcategories(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubSubcategory');
}
```

I am assuming you have a conventional database schema with ID and name columns for Categories tables. A query like this:-

```
$categories = Category::all();
```

from anywhere your application will now return all the Categories, then for every category, you'll have the subcategories and so on.